# Select a div in the page onload

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

Basically, the overflow of a certain div in the page is set to scroll vertically. I want the user to be able to scroll immediately after the page loads. In order to scroll, at this time you must first click on that div and then you can scroll.

How can I make this happen straight away? I would kindly ask you to refrain from document.location.hash methods as this seems to be causing some other problems within pages for some reason.

If you look at the page, the scrollable div is #mainView.

[Example page](http://www.niuzly.com/p/5053df08ea39d36930000001/2012-9-15)

Comment: What browser(and version of said browser) are you using?  I am unable to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use [`window.scroll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scroll). It even seems to be fairly well supported (IE9, Chrome, Firefox). IE8/7 I'm not so sure, since it doesn't recognize the `height: 100%` on the `html, body` elements.

For instance, here I will create twenty elements dynamically and set the `window.scroll` to the total height of the `div`, which in turn is (supposed to be) the same height as the `document.body` "height".

Try it out:

```
(function load(d) {
    var body = d.body,
        i = 0,
        div,
        winheight = h(),
        scroll = 0;

    (function loop() {
        if (i++ < 20) {
            scroll = scroll + 20 + 100 + 5 + winheight;

            div = document.createElement('div'); 
            div.style.height = winheight - 125 + 'px';
            div.className = 'block';
            div.innerHTML = 'DIV #' + i;

            document.body.appendChild(div);

            window.scroll(0, scroll);

            setTimeout(loop, 2000);
        }
    })();

    function h() {
        return Math.max(
            Math.max(body.scrollHeight, d.documentElement.scrollHeight),
            Math.max(body.offsetHeight, d.documentElement.offsetHeight),
            Math.max(body.clientHeight, d.documentElement.clientHeight)
        );
    }    
})(document);
```

[​Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/QCuAu/embedded/result/) ([Source](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/QCuAu/))